# Ember.js: how to use a parent model's property in a url path?

Tags: ember.js

In Ember.js if you have a model that has a one-to-many relationship is it possible to generate links based on a property of the parent model?

For example, I have a model and some data like this:

```
var SuggestionGroup = Ember.Model.extend({
   id: Ember.attr('number'),
   name: Ember.attr('string'),
   suggestions: Ember.hasMany('App.Suggestion', {
      key: 'suggestions',
      embedded: true
   })
});

SuggestionGroup.adapter = Ember.FixtureAdapter.create();

SuggestionGroup.FIXTURES = [
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Start',
    suggestions: [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Fetching coffee and cake for the Interface Developers',
            description: 'Because they\'re so brilliant',
            upVotes: 10,
            downVotes: 2
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: 'Criticising the app devs more',
            description: 'They enjoy a bit of banter',
            upVotes: 8,
            downVotes: 4
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            title: 'Not updating JIRA',
            description: 'It\'ll be funny when the PMs start raging',
            upVotes: 1000000,
            downVotes: 0
        }
    ]
}]
```

And here are my routes:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
   this.resource('current-suggestions');
   this.resource('suggestion', {
      path: '/current-suggestions/:suggestion_id'
   });
});
```

My template is like this:

```
{{#each model}}
<td>
    <ul>
    {{#each suggestions}}
        <li class="suggestion">
            <h3>
                {{#linkTo 'suggestion' this}}{{title}}{{/linkTo}}
            </h3>
        </li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</td>
{{/each}}
```

So, at the moment my paths are `current-suggestions/1`. But what I'd like to do is have paths such as `current-suggestions/Start/1`. So, the path is generated using a property from the parent model.

Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: Why not put a `belongsTo` relationship in the child? Then you can get a reference to the parent using get() and then get any properties you want.

Comment: @GJK It's not accessing the parent's properties that I'm having trouble with. I want to use the parent's `name` property to create a path for each `Suggestion`. So if a `Suggestion`'s parent has a `name` of 'Start' then the path will be `current-suggestions/Start/1` or if it's 'Stop' then `current-suggestions/Stop/1`.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I imagine the way to do it would be using a dynamic segment, but I'm not quite good enough to at Ember.js yet to know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last comment from @GJK was pointing already in the right direction, but let me propose a somewhat elaborate answer to your question.

One way you could do it is to hook into the `serialize` function of your `SuggestionRoute` and provide the missing dynamic segment your final url should have, conceptually this would be like this:

Add the extra dynamic segment to your route definition, in your case `:name`

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('current-suggestions');
  this.resource('suggestion', {
    path: '/current-suggestions/:name/:suggestion_id'
 });
});
```

And then provide the data for the dynamic segment like this:

```
App.SuggestionRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  ...
  serialize: function(model) {
    var id = model.get('id');
    var name = model.get('name');
    return {
        name: name, suggestion_id: id
    }
  }
});
```

**Note:** this solution assumes you provide the `name` property from your parent model for the `Suggestion` model, to achieve this you could rethink your model relationship's.

And to inspire you on how you could refactor your app to achieve your goal (having url's like `/current-suggestions/Start/1` etc.) have a look here:

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ebigit/4/edit)**

I've tried to simulate your use case but with a different approach.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks very much this is what I'm looking for. There's something strange going on with how the path is generated initially. You'll notice that the anchors' `href` contains a `null` where the name of the group should be. However, when you click on the link the url has the name instead of the `null`. And then if you then go back to the list of suggestions the anchors' `href` doesn't have `null` anymore. Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: The problem is that when the model first gets sent to the `serialize` method it has not been loaded. This is why none of the model's properties are defined (this seems like a bug to me). I managed to get around this by listening for when the models had been loaded and then triggering a re-render of the template.